# How do I access to session on the server?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

everyone.
my sessions work correctly when I use it locally, but when in deploy on the server this error occurred :

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I deploy very simply project but it does not work again

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Session["name"] = "javad bayat";
            ViewBag.Message = Session["name"].ToString();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            try
            {

            ViewBag.Message = Session["name"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception w)
            {

                ViewBag.Message = w.Message;
            }

            return View();
        }
```

do I have to check the windows server or config my web.config to sth else?
thanks for your help

Comment: Which operation throws the exception?  What's the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: I presume you mean the `Session["name"]` is null when called from the `About` action. Have you confirmed that this has already been created? Is the session being held inproc or is it using some other service? Is the application being served using single server or is it being balanced across a few?

Comment: there is a single server and I create Session["name"] in the Index method and I want use it in the about method or in index method when I use Session["name"].ToString() throw an exception  .but when I want to use Session["name"].ToString() it throws an exception that session is null.  on localhost it works correctly